# Python import error

Tags: python, ubuntu, import

I am trying to run a python file from the command line with a single parameter in Ubuntu 12.04. The program works if I simply run it from the IDE and pass the parameter in the code. However, if I call 'python readFromSerial1.py 3' in the command prompt, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readFromSerial1.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()   
  File "readFromSerial1.py", line 6, in main
    readDataFromUSB(time)
  File "readFromSerial1.py", line 9, in readDataFromUSB
    import usb.core
ImportError: No module named usb.core
```

I'm a little confused as the module imports correctly if I run from the IDE. I download the pyUSB module and extracted it (its filename is pyusb-1.0.0a3). I then copied this file into 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. Is that the correct procedure? I have a feeling the issue is due to python simply not being able to find the usb module and I need to put it in the correct location. My code is below, and any help would be greatly appreciated:

### readFromSerial1.py

```
import sys

def main():
    time = sys.argv[1]
    #time = 1
    readDataFromUSB(time)

def readDataFromUSB(time):
    import usb.core


    #find device
    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x099e, idProduct=0x0001) #GPS info

    #Was the device found?
    if dev is None:
        raise ValueError('Device not found')
    else:
        print "Device found!"

    #Do this to avoid 'Errno16: Resource is busy'
    if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0):
        try:
            dev.detach_kernel_driver(0)
        except usb.core.USBError as e:
            sys.exit("Could not detach kernel driver: %s" % str(e))

    #Sets default config
    dev.set_configuration()

    #Gets default endpoint
    endpoint = dev[0][(0,0)][0]



    writeObject = open("InputData.txt", "w")

    #iterate for time purposes
    for i in range(0, (time*6)):    #sys.argv is command line variable for time input
        data = dev.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress, endpoint.wMaxPacketSize, 0, 100000)
        sret = ''.join([chr(x) for x in data])

        writeObject.write(sret);

        print sret
        '''
        newStr = ''.join(sret[7:14])

        compareStr = ",*4F"

        if (newStr == compareStr):
            print "The GPS is not reading in any values right now. Try going somewhere else with better reception."

        else:
            print sret[7:14]

        '''

    writeObject.close()


main()
```

Comment: Is the version of python run through your IDE the same as the version run on the command line?

Comment: You have to cd into the directory that the module `usb` is initialized in, and then run your script

Comment: My command line version is 2.73, my eclipse version is 2.7.5. Is it enough that they are both 2.7? If not, which one is easier to change?

Comment: I'd suggest installing pyusb like shown in [documentation](https://github.com/walac/pyusb)

Comment: Try installing the module for both versions.

Comment: @enginefree I'm pretty sure I've already done that. It works if I run it through the IDE, just not if I call the program through the command prompt

Comment: Then show us your file hierarchy so we can understand where everything is.

Comment: @enginefree +1 Reviewing my hierarchy made me see my error. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just put the solution in your question so that other users might resolve the same problem.